# It seems that session was not destroyed precisely in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I tried to destroy my `'session'`, but it seems session is accessible Properly after that destruction. even I checked it by 'isActive' and got a response:
`'false'` but it's still readable and writable yet.

```
$session=Yii::$app->session;
$session->close();
$session->destroy();
$session->isActive ? $m='ya' : $m='no';
echo $m; // responded 'false'
$_SESSION['test']=1; //session is accessible properly yet
echo $_SESSION['test']; // session response 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION` is a `PHP` global var 
[**`PHP:SESSION-DOCS`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

> An associative array containing session variables available to the
>   current script. See the Session functions documentation for more
>   information on how this is used.

This means that `$_SESSION` is always active .. `destroy()` should "destroy" the actual content of the `$_SESSION`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#destroy()-detail

**`destroy()`**

In detail Frees all session variables and destroys all data registered to a session.